# Serialization vs Assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is serialization an appropriate solution to the following setup?

I have a client model and would like to keep track of a sets of dates for each client.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :contact_dates, :recertification_dates
  serialize :contact_dates
  serialize :recertification_dates
end
```

It seems like overkill to use child models that would only hold a single date in each record so this seems appropriate.

However, the thing I'm worried about is the performance implications when I would like to report on this data in the future. Is de-serialization going to make running reports take forever? I'm not expecting more than a few thousand clients and approx. 20 dates per serialized field.

Thanks!

Comment: serialization should not affect the speed but would be hard to query those fields